# Java: I can't put my actionlistener outside the constructor

Tags: java, multithreading, constructor, chat, actionlistener

```
public Server(){
 start.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try{    
                port = Integer.parseInt(portInput.getText());
            }
            catch(NumberFormatException e){
                text.append("");
            }

        }

 });


}
```

Having the actionlistener inside the constructor, I can't use the append method becacuse it tells me to add a Server cast to `text.append("");`

When I do this it tells me I "Cannot cast from JTextArea to Server"

When I move the action listener outside of the constructor it gives me an error and basically forces me to put the action listener inside the constructor. So what I want is to be able to have the action listener outside the constructor so I can call the `append` method inside the actionlistener.

At this point I'm not sure what to do. I'm sure its something minor, but I just can't figure it out. Any help please?

Comment: "When I move the action listener outside of the constructor it gives me an error..." -- What error might that be?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend putting the listener outside the constructor. What is the exact error you're getting when trying to call ```eventsLog.appendEventsLog("");```?

Comment: @azurefrog it's kinda hard to explain, it basically says "Syntax error, insert "}" to complete MethodBody" after the semicolon at the end of the actionlistener when I move it outside the constructor. It also tells me to remove the override annotation and "Delete this token }" the bracket that denotes the end of the constructor

Comment: @JornVernee please read above

Comment: It's hard to tell from a verbal description what's going on.  Please post the code with the listener outside the constructor that is giving you the error.

Comment: You can't just copy the listener outside of the constructor, you would have to make a separate (nested) class. And you lose the convenience of being able to automatically capture ```port```, ```portInput``` and ```eventsLog```. That's why I wouldn't recommend doing that/

Comment: Try changing the line ```eventsLog.appendEventsLog("");``` to ```appendEventsLog("");```

Comment: Could you please put the rest of your code? I want to know where eventsLog is defined in the class and what type it is.

Comment: @lordoku eventsLog is a JTextArea, it's defined before the constructor, type public. I don't want to post more code because it will get too long

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to first present working code based for the addActionListener in constructor case, I took the liberty of introducing missing fields.

```
public class ServerGUI {

    private final JButton startServer = new JButton("Start server");
    int port;
    private JTextField portInput = new JTextField();
    private JTextArea eventsLog = new JTextArea();

    public ServerGUI(){
        startServer.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try{
                    port = Integer.parseInt(portInput.getText());
                }
                catch(NumberFormatException nfe){
                    appendEventsLog("");
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void appendEventsLog(String msg) {
        String text = eventsLog.getText();
        eventsLog.setText(text + "\n" + msg);
    }
}
```

The problem here was that appendEventsLog is not a member of JTextArea but a member of ServerGUI.

For the second case assigning ActionListener to JButton outside the constructor you have to use static code block or what I prefer initialise method

```
public class ServerGUI {

    private final JButton startServer = new JButton("Start server");
    int port;
    private JTextField portInput = new JTextField();
    private JTextArea eventsLog = new JTextArea();

    public ServerGUI(){
        initalise();
    }

    private void initalise() {
        startServer.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try{
                    port = Integer.parseInt(portInput.getText());
                }
                catch(NumberFormatException nfe){
                    appendEventsLog("");
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void appendEventsLog(String msg) {
        String text = eventsLog.getText();
        eventsLog.setText(text + "\n" + msg);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are actually not handing over any string at

> eventsLog.appendEventsLog("");

I´m not shure if it has to do with your problem or if you just forgot to type it.

Comment: that's irrelevant, I put a string inside another listener I get the same error